# submit a job from eclipse to a running cluster on amazon EMR

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I want to add jobs from my java code in eclipse to a running cluster of EMR for saving startup time (creating ec2, bootstrapping...).

I know how to run a new cluster from java code but it's terminating after all jobs are done.

```
RunJobFlowRequest runFlowRequest = new RunJobFlowRequest()
        .withName("Some name")
        .withInstances(instances)
        // .withBootstrapActions(bootstrapActions)
        .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
        .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
        .withSteps(firstJobStep, secondJobStep, thirdJobStep)
        .withLogUri("s3n://path/to/logs");

// Run the jobs
RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = mapReduce
        .runJobFlow(runFlowRequest);
String jobFlowId = runJobFlowResult.getJobFlowId();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` parameter to `TRUE`, otherwise the cluster will be terminated after executing all the steps. If this property is set, the cluster will continue in waiting state after executing all the steps.

Add `.withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)` to the existing code.

Refer this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_RunJobFlow.html) for further details.